# How to add typing to getQuery(event) in Nuxt 3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, typescript-typings, nuxtjs3

In my Nuxt 3 application, I have an API implementation:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const { year } = getQuery(event);
    // remaining logic
}
```

How can I add typing to the `year` query param?

I have tried doing:

```
interface queryInterface {
    year: number;
}

const { year }: queryInterface = getQuery(event);
```

But apparently that's not the way, it shows error of:

`Property 'year' is missing in type 'QueryObject' but required in type 'queryInterface'.`

Comment: How about `const {year: number} = getQuery(event)`?

Comment: @KiranParajuli that would be renaming `year` variable to `number` , not adding typing 

Comment: :D, my bad. I think logging `getQuery` method can help you debugging `console.log(getQuery(event))`. You can check if `year` is actually present in the result.

Comment: (Here)[https://www.jsdocs.io/package/h3#getQuery] `getQuery` returns type `ufo.QueryObject` but I couldn't find what was.  What makes you think that has `year` member?

Comment: @CraigHicks `year` is a query param I defined myself for my api route.
My api route is something like: `/api/records?year=2023`

Hence I am asking about how can I add typing for my `year` param

Answer (score 2):

H3 1.8.0 was just released with support for [typed event handlers](https://unjs.io/blog/2023-08-15-h3-towards-the-edge-of-the-web). This will be landed on the next Nuxt release:

```
export default eventHandler<{ body: { name: string }; query: { id: string } }>(
  (event) => {
    const query = getQuery(event) // Query is typed as { id: string }
    const body = await readBody(event) // Body is typed as { name: string }
  },
)
```

For now, you can install h3@1.8.0 to your Nuxt app until they release the next version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `getQuery()` returns a type `QueryObject` you can take your interface `QueryInterface` and make it `extend` that `QueryObject`.

```
interface QueryInterface extends QueryObject {
  year: number;
}

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { year }: QueryInterface = getQuery(event);
  // remaining logic
});
```

P. S. Query parameters are usually `string`s. So consider typing `year` as such unless you know for sure that year will always be of type `number`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the recommended way but you can use the 'Type Assertion'

```js
interface QueryObject {
    year: number
}
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    const { year } = getQuery(event) as unknown as QueryObject
    return year
})
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error which you are getting is due to the mismatch of return type between `getQuery()` method and `queryInterface`.

Can you please try this way **:**

```
interface QueryInterface {
  year: number;
}

const { year } = getQuery<QueryInterface>(event);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, getQuery function doesn't accept generic typing